# evaluating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}(3x)-\tan^{-1}(x)}{x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{(\tan^{-1}(3x)-\tan^{-1}(x))}{x}\,dx.$$
I tried to evaluate this integral in the following way but got  wrong answer ,the actual answer is $\frac{\pi \ln3}{2}$ but i am getting the answer as 0 using following method -

We can write this as $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}(3x)3\,dx}{3x}-\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)\,dx}{x}.$$ If we substitute 3x=t in first integral , we get the answer as $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}(t)\,dt}{t}-\int_0^\infty \frac{\tan^{-1}(x)\,dx}{x} =0$$ .
Why does this happen ?

Comment: The integrals you’ve broken it into go to $\infty,$ and $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: You can use the linearity of integral sign only if the integrals are convergent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is simply a [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) with the choice $f(x) = \tan^{-1} x$, $a = 3$, $b = 1$.  You cannot separate the integrand in the way you have done, because the individual terms are not convergent on their own, like how $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \ne \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{\arctan(3x)-\arctan(x)}{x} = \int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{x^2 t^2+1}\,dt \tag{1}$$
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(3x)-\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{1}^{3}\frac{1}{x^2 t^2+1}\,dt\,dx\\
&\stackrel{\text{Fubini}}{=}&\int_{1}^{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2 t^2+1}\,dx \,dt\\&=&\int_{1}^{3}\frac{\pi}{2t}\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\log 3.}\tag{2} \end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Excellent! (+1)